# What is The Nuget Package For System.Web.Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, nuget-package

I have been researching but I can't seem to find any relevant answer. I will appreciate it if someone told me the nuget package to install in asp.net webapi application for System.Web.Hosting

I need it to use `Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("")`

Comment: Try entire namespace.
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Empty);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Web` assembly, you will then be able to access System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment

Answer (score 3):

Since this is in the `System` namespace, its very likely part of the Framework.

Googling for that namespace brings it up on MSDN.  So, open up the documentation for that namespace on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.appdomaininfoenum(v=vs.110).aspx).  Click on any class in the list, it doesn't matter which.

You will see something like this:

> Namespace:   System.Web.Hosting
>   Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)

You now know which assembly this particular class is in, which likely also contains most of the rest of the desired namespace.  Check another class on MSDN to confirm.  Well, this is `System.Web`.  That's part of the Framework.

If you do this for another namespace and can't find it on MSDN, you're probably looking for a Nuget package.  But in this case, nope.  Just add a reference to the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

System.Web is not a nugget package.

Go to Solution explorer > References > Add References > Framework > look for System.Web.

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

For .Net Core use

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`